# Getting format error when exporting HTML table to Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I am exporting an HTML table to Excel in c#  but when open the excel it is giving me error like:

[image]

I tried a different extension with "office document.spreadsheetml.sheet" like .xlsx also still giving the same error. Below is my C# code:

```
//StrExport.Append(@"<html xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:Spreadsheet'  xmlns:ss='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:Spreadsheet'  xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'><head><title>Time</title>");
        //StrExport.Append(@"<body lang=EN-US id=h1><div class=Section1>");
        StrExport.Append(@"<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'><head><title>Time</title>");
        StrExport.Append(@"<body lang=EN-US style='mso-element:header' id=h1><span style='mso--code:DATE'></span><div class=Section1>");
        StrExport.Append("<DIV  style='font-size:12px;'>");
        StrExport.Append(dvInfo.InnerHtml);
        StrExport.Append("</div></body></html>");
        string strFile = "StudentInformations.xls";
      //  string strFile = "StudentInformations.xlsx";
        string strcontentType = "application/excel";
        //string strcontentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.BufferOutput = true;
        Response.ContentType = strcontentType;
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strFile);
        Response.Write(StrExport.ToString());
        Response.Flush();            
        Response.End();
```

Please provides solution of this message.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected.
You are exporting HTML, but calling it .xlsx.  Excel is clever enough to interpret it, but you will get this warning.

To have no warning, you need to build the output in native .xlsx format, using a readily available library.

Comment: I also set extension .xlsx but when set xlsx excel not open.

Comment: @jitendrakumar The _content_ matters, not the extension. How about setting the extension to PNG; does it magically make the content an image?

Comment: @uwe Keim Any solution??

Comment: @jitendrakumar Did you read the answer?  You need to use a library to build XLSX output natively.  Your code just renders HTML and calls it an Excel file.